# Angular routing: Error when using direct path of a specified URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I need some assistance with my routing setup in Angular. I am running on v12 of Angular.

I get a **404 Not Found** error when trying to hit the direct URL for "register" in the following example URL: somesite.com/**register**.

I'm not sure whether this is a server or Angular issue. Here is my code for the router module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RegistrationPageComponent } from './registration-page/registration-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register', component: RegistrationPageComponent },
  // { path: 'register', redirectTo: '/register', pathMatch: 'full' }, // NOTE: I have tried this too
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/register', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/register', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

All other aspects of the routing work fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Likely a server issue. You need to setup your server so it rewrites all requests for unknown resources to your angular index.html

Comment: Do you use the <router-outlet> tag in some page like app-component? Angular need this tag to render the section of content in main page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like your nginx server (if you are using one) does not reroute correctly. To handle this you have to change your nginx configuration files, which you can find here:

**Ubuntu 16.04+ / Debian 8+**

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**CentOS 7 / Red Hat 7**

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

To rewrite all requests use this method to catch all URIs and forward them to your index.html:

```
location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index  index.html;

     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}
```

If you want more complex rerouting behaviours or are using some other server configuration then at least you might know now what to look for.